# Reporting Software C#

Tags: c#

Which reporting software for Visual C# do you know? We need reports to be directly included in our application (not as a separate program), and the reports should feature matrix tables (sometimes called tablix or crosstabs), as well as several tables in the same report, with dynamically growing size and changing position.

We have used SAP Crystal Reports in our application so far, but it has a couple of disadvantages, such as: it has to be installed separately, instead of being installed together with the application as a set of DLL files; also, the designer sometimes makes problems and we do not always have the possibility to add new data sets correctly.

We have tried the following alternatives so far: MS Reports, FastReport.Net, DevExpress, List & Label, ActiveReports, Stimulsoft. All of these have some issues.

Comment: Have you check SyncFunction's Report Server?

Comment: We have taken a look at the website. It mentions WPF but our application is made using Windows Forms, which is not mentioned there. Does the program support Windows Forms too?

Comment: OK, apparently it does support Windows Forms, but the website does not mention matrix (or tablix, or crosstab) tables. Is this type of table supported?

Comment: Why don't you contact them to find out. They might support it or willing to have a look for you...